# How to change sync pulse into pulse signal

Tags: ltspice, mains, monostable

From this application note :
https://www.renesas.com/br/en/document/apn/cm-318-dc-power-line-communication

I want to change sync pulse into pulse to process in microcontroller
[image]

I am thinking to use monostable by NE555 but still stuck. here is my simulation and circuit.
[image]

Could you tell me how to change sync pulse into normal pulse, please?

---

**Updated**

I have experimented with the circuit above in LTSpice, it worked.
These are the results.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Still trying to convert impulse signal into squrewave. I'll update later.

---

**Updated:**

May be I found the answer but still in simulation.
I use CD4093B which is NAND gate with schmitt trigger input to shape impulse signal into square wave. Even though the wave form doesn't same as the application note but I think I can use this for future processing. Any update will let you know.

[image]

Comment: Rectify pulses around VDD/2 and then amplify with an opamp or comparator.

Comment: Thanks for quickly reply, I'll try.

Comment: I found this:
http://www.seekic.com/circuit_diagram/Electrical_Equipment_Circuit/EDGE_DETECTOR.html

Do you think CD4096 will help?

Answer (score 1):

Use a circuit like this one followed by an amplifier ...

You should use the first rise-time of "Vr2" for "triggering". This happens to all 8 us.
Made with FREE [microcap v12](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulml1ukc1xv1h2w/mc12cd.zip?dl=0).

[image]

Here is circuit completed ...

[image]

And when the pulses are alternated ...

[image]

One can show very little delay added.

Comment: Thanks for giving me an idea. What is the name of circuit you use?

Comment: At the left of Vs, it is the generator of pulse (simplified). Op amps are TLV2772 and circuit is double rectifiers followed by a "little" first order filter.

Comment: Thank you for a very clear explanation.

Comment: Your generated input signal doesn't match the waveform.  Therefore, if you apply your circuit to the actual proposed input, your output pulses will not consistently be 8µs apart.  They will alternate between shorter and longer gaps between pulses.  The main difficulty in solving this specific problem is that the tri-level-sync pulses alternate direction every period.

Comment: @SteKulov Do you have idea of how to detect tri-level-sync pulses?

Comment: @Ste Kulov The fact that the tri-level pulses alternate every "period" does not "matter really" (shown in my other simulation).

Comment: Ah, I see.  They're not perfectly aligned, but I guess it depends how much jitter is acceptable.  Thanks for clarifying and editing!

Comment: @Nott  This circuit seems like it does a pretty good job unless you need the sync reference point to be the tall edges in the middle, which is needed for analog high-definition video.  I don't think you do need that since your input waveform from the application note doesn't measure the periods from those points.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. My application doesn't need that high of precision. I just need pulses at every around 8 uS is acceptable. I'll investigate more about circuit that Antonio51 gave me. Any update I'll let you know.

Thanks.